# Firebase iOS Messaging, didReceiveMessage, appData is deprecated

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting appData is deprecated below with the new Firebase project.  What else should I use for data messages only?

```
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"Received data message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);

    if(remoteMessage.appData[@"action"] != nil)
    {
        if([@"refresh" isEqual: remoteMessage.appData[@"action"]])
        {
            [[FIRInstanceID instanceID]deleteIDWithHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                if(error == nil) {

                }
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios:

*Deprecated FCM direct channel messaging via shouldEstablishDirectChannel. Instead, use APNs for downstream message delivery. Add content_available key to your payload if you want to continue use legacy APIs, but we strongly recommend HTTP v1 API as it provides full APNs support.*